# DPDK mempool & hugepage configuration for the highest throughput

Tags: server, network-programming, dpdk

I have a DPDK app running which currently handles around 5.5 Million incoming pps and forwards them, each packet is sized around 74Bytes so 5.5M pps is around 390MB/s or 3.1Gbit/s (more to go to saturate 10Gbit/s).
In the server, my NIC has 10G capability, 56 cores, and **reserved 20GB RAM for DPDK** out of 64GB.
I am working on scalability, so **the reserved memory is more than enough maybe?**
though I reserved 20GB for a total huge page, 10G for NUMA node 0, and 10G for NUMA node 1. but currently I am only using cores in NUMA node 0 only for better cache locality.

I used mempool for port memory allocation created by "rte_pktmbuf_pool_create()" and "rte_malloc()" for other allocation. Now **what param ("required_num_mbuf") should I use in rte_pktmbuf_pool_create() to make the best use of my memory to increase performance?** considering I will be using around 28 cores, SINGLE NIC port(should I ask the vendor for multiple that the difference will be noticable?), 10-15 rx queues, 10-15 tx queues, and around 20-30 rte_ring's

**I used pagesize of 2Mb, total 10Gb hugepage for NUMA node 0, is it ok or should I try increase the pagesize for better performance?**